# My friends in facebook can't see the "likes" I'm doing in my website. and I can't see theirs.

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, xfbml

I have looked here and in google search and I haven't find something relative to my problem. And I have checked the privacy setting. I'm not blocking anyone from seen my posts.

**My problem is this:**

On my website page: http://ctrlartdesigns.com/special_offer.html there is a "Like" button and when I click it. it shows me on the button it self that I like it and when I go to my profile page in facebook. I can see the post in my wall. But my friends can't see it. I have testing with several users and I can't see the "like" they did appearing in their wall. Just they can see it not me. So it goes ways.

As well I have been waited almost 10 minutes to see if it will appear with delay but, still I can't see it. Please help me. and I hope I have been clearly enough.

What seems to be the problem?
I'm using the XFBML code from http://developers.facebook.com.

Thanks to the helpers.
All the best.

Comment: Can you please try using iframe, and please post the code here if it doesn't work too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, and I am sure this has to do with all the "likejacking" spam that was happening...

facebook likes do not show up in the News Feed any more. If you are looking for something that does, the Share button would be your next best choice.

Comment: I think you right about the "likejacking" it's working now. Thank you